# How to add Score and Timer in Adobe flash

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi guys I am new in actionscript programming and i can't find to get this right.

I need to have a score and timer in this game >>> http://www.filedropper.com/eggrun

It should have coins for adding the score and a countdown timer for it's gaming time.

Please help me guys :(

I am nowhere close to getting this right. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code would be helpfull. But to make a simple countdown timer try this!
I'm assuming ur coding on the 'Timeline'

```
var count:Number = 60; //Count down from 60

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,count);// Timer intervall in ms

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);//EventListener for intervalls
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, countdownComplete);
myTimer.start();//start Timer

function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void {
countDownTextField.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount); 
//Display Time in a textfield on stage, 
//i'll call it countDownTextField. U will have to create it first
}

function countdownComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
   // fires when the countdown is finished
   removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);//stops the game
   addChild(scoreScreen); //You have to create a Sprite or MovieClip with a TextField
   scoreScreen.scoreText.text = score.toString() // and then assign the score to the textField
//to start the game again just remove the scoreScreen and call the init() function
   myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);//remove listers
   myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, countdownComplete);

}
```

if u need a method for when the timer is finished, add a TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE Listener!

PLease explain what you mean with

> it should have coins for adding the score

the best way to handle your score is by useing a function

```
var score:int = 0;
function updateScore(addScore:int):void{
    score += addScore;

}
```

and then just call it whenever u need to update the score like this

```
updateScore(10);// adds 10 to the score
```

Comment: what I need is when the countdown timer goes to zero. The game stops then the stage will remove the game scene then a new layer will pop up with the total score in it. Please look/download my game at >>> http://www.filedropper.com/eggrun. So you guys can see my codes on it.

Comment: Like is said b4, for this u must listen to the TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE Event! Ive updated the answer!

Comment: The game doesn't stop when the 60 second timer expires to 0. What should i do with the score screen??.. I made a new layer then add a static text field. Is that correct sir?

Comment: @HeOne First of all, do not put instances on different layers. And you're gonna have to upload some code. That website you linked to seems to be only for "premium members."

Comment: Huh you can download my flash file >>> filedropper.com/eggrun for free. Just click on the Download this File.. Please help me sir :(

Comment: Help me please @M4tchB0X3r David please :(. I am still new to this,

Comment: look at my flash file >>> http://www.filedropper.com/test_37. CS5
 
I now have some coins for the score, and the score is now adding up..
 
I also have the countdown timer, but the timer doesn't stop at 0 it still goes on. It goes on to negative numbers (-1, -2, and so on...) 
 
Please help me fix it guys..

Comment: are u sure u pass both arguments to the timer? new Timer(1000,count);
count beeing the number if times the timer fires!
i've updated the countdownComplete, add the removeListeners!
please mark answer as correct when ure done ;)

Comment: No problem, but please mark as answerd ;) tick mark next to Answer!

Comment: thanks a lot sir:) can you please help me again on this one :) Pleaaase I am so noob.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081730/how-to-set-objects-on-a-androidh-runner-game

Comment: uhmmm @M4tchB0X3r do you have any idea about that.. Please help me sir, I am still new to this programming.