# How to set objects on a androidH runner game

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I am trying to develop a android runner game for school purpose..
I am still new to this and please I need your assistance..

You guys can view my CS5flash file at >>> http://www.filedropper.com/test_37

The obstacles and coins are on random. But the obstacles and coins are overlapping each other.. Which is very bad for a runner game because it looks very bad and the gameplay gets very very complicated.

How can i fix it??. Is there any way to fix it?.

And i am also thinking if I can set the obstacles and coins to a specific area (not on random). So the game will be more oganized and the  gameplay won't be complicated. Which i still don't know -_-.

But i still prefer it on random. So guys please help me fix it..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the way you are adding the coins and obstacles! I suggest using a timer for each. Atm you are adding a ton of them on every frame, calculating overlaps would use too much resources! and put them in an `array` or better a `vector`! i would reccomend using an `object Pool` aswell!

so limit the amout of coins and hurdles that can be present, like 5 or so. then remove them from the array/vector when they are offscreen or collected! then when you add new stuff you can check against the array/vector what the allowed values are!

when you got your Array you can pass it to the `randomRange()` function and exlcude those values!
would look somthing like this! not testet!!

```
function randomRange (min:Number, max:Number, exclude:Array = null):int
{
    var val:int = (min + Math.random() * (max - min)) >> 0;
    if (exclude)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < exclude; i++)
        {
            while ((val < exclude[i].x + exclude[i].width) && (val > exclude[i].x))
            {
                val = (min + Math.random() * (max - min)) >> 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Its still quite exspensive performance wise. but with only a few object you should be fine

Comment: Wait i'll try to code it. Thanks BTW :) So first i have to make an array.. Right?

Comment: Waaaaaaaaa I can't get it right! :(( Please help me M4tchB0X3r . The deadline is very near already. Please help me pleasssssssssse